# Disabling certain options in Visual Studio 2010, when one option is selected

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Hi guys Im using Visual Studio 2010 C sharp.
Basically Im building a program and I want to be able to disable certain options after one option is selected. For example when you fill out an online form for something like a job application and it asks do you have a degree? If you select no then the next options below related to the degree question are disabled. That is what I basically want to do.

I couldnt upload the image im affraid :(

Basically as you can see, what I want to do when RDP is selected the 'Site URL' becomes disabled but when any of the other web browser options are selected the 'RDP Connection' is disabled.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hi I figured out how to do this, I thought I would post it here in case it would be any help to anyone else/

Basically it was the use of just and if statement -_-" (cant believe I didnt think of it)

Basically below is a section of my script associated with the combo box I made. There are two options in the combo box, one if internet connection and one is RDP connection. When either one is selected it will 'hide' or 'show' certain data boxes below.

```
 private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboBox1.Text == "Internet Browser")
        {

            label4.Visible = false;
            comboBox2.Visible = false;
            btnCreate.Visible = false;
            label5.Visible = true;
            textBox3.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            label4.Visible = true;
            comboBox2.Visible = true;
            btnCreate.Visible = true;
            label5.Visible = false;
            textBox3.Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

Its basic boolean, if you have any problems, message me and I will help. Happy coding =)